# Wireshark dissector UINT64 bitmasking

Tags: c, wireshark, bitmask, wireshark-dissector, uint64

I see that the bitmask field in the `header_field` used in `proto_register_field_array(const int parent, hf_register_info *hf, const int num_records);` is a `guint32`, therefor I cannot use a 64 bit mask. Is there anyway I can go around?

Specifically, I have a 60 bit field so I am trying to create a field with type `FT_UINT64`and bitmask `0xfffffffffffffff`for that matter, but of course, when compiling the C code i get:

```
warning: implicit conversion from 'long' to 'guint32' (aka 'unsigned int') changes value from 1152921504606846975 to 4294967295 [-Wconstant-conversion]
            NULL, 0xfffffffffffffff,
```

Thank you in advance for a response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep searching, it seems like the only possible solution is to forget about bitmasking in the header field definition and use the `proto_tree_add_bits_item(proto_tree *tree, const int hf_index, tvbuff_t *tvb, const guint bit_offset, const gint no_of_bits, const guint encoding);` function.

Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0):

If the function takes a 32 bit parameter, there is no way you can force it to understand a 64 bit parameter, sorry. Look for if some other function can do what you want.

Comment: Yes I know that, that's kind of what I was going for. If anyone would know if there was some function or something in Wireshark I can use.